# Pass Environment flags while building Xcode project

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, build, testflight

I am generally share build with TestFlight from Bitrise. we release build for 2 group. 1 for internal tester and 2. for external/client.

problem is that I want some feature enable or disable based on the group which I am sharing TestFlight build. for ex if I release build for internal than personal data/token share to analytic which help to debug in case of error and disable for external tester or final release.

for that I don't want to create new schemes or config. I want to handle with environment variable which can be pass compile time and those variable use in code and enable/disable feature.